# How to I determine the default value for a given function parameter at runtime?

Tags: python

Using python 2.4, I'm attempting to identify, at runtime, which of an arbitrary function's arguments have default values. Unfortunately, although I can find what the default values are, I can't seem to get a handle on which parameters they correspond to. For example:

```
def foo(a, b, c=5):
    return a + b + c

import inspect
inspect.getargspec(foo) # output is: (['a', 'b', 'c'], None, None, (5,))
```

The output of `getargspec` is clearer in python 2.6, which returns a named tuple:

`ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(5,))`

Python obviously has enough information to accomplish the task during execution. How can I get at it?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the tuple, it's just not decorated with metadata which makes it easier to interpret. They're actually both tuples, but in 2.6, it's a named tuple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arguments with default values must follow arguments without default values.
So if there are any defaults, they must correspond to the arguments at the tail end of `args`.

In your case, `args=['a','b','c']`, and `defaults=(5,)`. So the default must correspond to `c`.

```
import inspect

def foo(a, b, c=5):
    return a + b + c
def show_defaults(f):
    args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(f) 
    if defaults:
        for arg, default in zip(args[-len(defaults):], defaults):
            print('{a} = {d}'.format(a=arg,d=default))

show_defaults(foo)
# c = 5
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec), it discusses the value for `defaults`:

> if this tuple has n elements, they
>   correspond to the last n elements
>   listed in args.

In your case `defaults` contains one value and corresponds to the last element listed in `args`, which is `c`.

Comment: What? You're suggesting that I read the documentation? That's crazy talk! ;o) Yeah, so I'm not sure how I failed to do that...but you caught me red-handed. Thanks for answer, and the gentle reminder.